# Monitor<T> class implementation in c++11 and c++03?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, synchronization

Herb Sutter describes implementation of template Monitor class in "C++ and Beyond 2012: Herb Sutter - C++ Concurrency":

```
template<class T> class monitor {
private:
     mutable T t;
     mutable std::mutex m;
public:
     monitor( T t_ ) : t( t_ ) { }

     template<typename F>
     auto operator()( F f ) const -> decltype(f(t))
     {  std::lock_guard<mutex> hold{m};  return f(t);  }
};
```

I am trying to wrap my existing class Logger:

```
Logger logger;
monitor< Logger > synchronizedLogger( logger ) ;
```

I have two questions.
Why does this code do not compile in Visual Studio 2012 with c++11?
Compiler says that " 'Debug' : is not a member of 'monitor' ", where Debug is a method of Logger class.

How to implement the same monitor template class with C++03 compiler using Boost library.

Comment: Are you calling `synchronizedLogger.Debug()` by any chance?

Comment: I can not see any of your code using something named `Debug` so it is hard to tell what it refers to

Comment: As a related note, I think Sutter states that the monitor is a kind of anti-pattern, and then presents a better solution. I cobbled together a working version of that solution [here](http://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/03/01/concurrent-object-wrapper-c11/), but it is strictly C++11.

Comment: The problem is in the code you are not showing.

Comment: @juanchopanza He doesn't really present it as an anti-pattern. He just says that for things like logging, it's not necessarily enough because the () operation is still likely to block at some point. But if that's not an issue there's no problem with this monitor class.

Comment: @cooky451 I think there is an issue, because you cannot guarantee that the locking granularity is right. If the wrapped type has an interface that doesn't play well with concurrent access (like most std lib containers) then you can still get race conditions.

Comment: @juanchopanza Hm.. I can't think of a problem here, but maybe you're right. Could you present an example where this could explode with standard containers?

Comment: @cooky451 it is the same problem that you get if you do the monitor by hand, that is, locking every method. Say you want to pop an element from a queue. You check  if q.empty(), then you pop if it isn't. Each operation is locked individually. But between the check, and the pop, the queue *might* become emptied by other threads. Your thread still thinks it is not empty, pops, and kaboom.

Comment: @cooky451 but the main point is not that, but the fact that the monitoring is blocking to the caller. Sutter spends most of the talk explaining how blocking is evil in these days of user interactive apps.

Comment: @juanchopanza Checking on empty() and then calling pop() can be done without any problems in one lambda. And that Sutter says the problem is that it's blocking is _literally_ what I wrote in my first comment here. <.<

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are likely trying to do something like `monitor< Logger >::Debug(...)` call. This won't work.

Your monitor can call functions
try:

```
monitor< Logger > logger;
logger(boost::bind(&Logger::Debug, _1, "blah"));
```

PS: *I haven't used C++11 lambdas, not to make mistakes I provided boost::bind version*

**edit**: Dave kindly supplied that version

```
logger([](Logger& l){ l.Debug("blah"); });
```

Comment: `logger([](Logger& l){ l.Debug("blah"); });`

Comment: @Dave: could a template-d form for this call be provided?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answers and comments.
There is my implementation of monitor< T > using C++03 and Boost library after your help.

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/result_of.hpp>

template<class T> class monitor
{
private:
     mutable T& t;
     mutable boost::mutex m;
public:
     monitor( T& t_ ) : t( t_ )
     {
     }

     template< typename F >
     typename boost::result_of< F() >::type operator()( F f ) const
     {
          boost::lock_guard< boost::mutex > hold( m );
          return f( t );
     }
};
```

Talking about correctness of this solution ( coarse granularity of locks and so on ) I am considering using this class as a wrapper for Google Mock implementation of my ILogger interface in unit tests. Google mock documentation states that it is not thread safe on windows.

```
 ILogger * mockedLogger = new MockedLogger();
 monitor< ILogger > synchronizedLogger( *mockedLogger ) ;
 synchronizedLogger( boost::bind( &ILogger::Debug, _1, "blah" ) );
```